# javascript/ add function to prototype in repl.it

Tags: javascript, replit

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMO-LTOrJaE).

```
function Bear(type){
  this.type = type;
}

Bear.prototype.growl = function(){
  console.log('grrr')
}

var grizzly = new Bear('grizzly')
var bBear = new Bear('bBear')

console.log(grizzly, bBear, Bear.growl)
```

the result of this sould be:

```
{
  "type": "grizzly",
  "growl": function(){
  console.log('grrr')
}
} {
  "type": "bBear",
  "growl": function(){
  console.log('grrr')
}
} undefined
```

but what I get in [repl.it](https://repl.it/@ChristofStanits/javascript-prototype-tutorial) is:

```
Bear { type: 'grizzly' } Bear { type: 'bBear' }
```

If I put the same code in a SO code snippet, the result is correct.

Why do I get different results here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an artifact of how different environments log objects. On Stack Overflow, Stack Snippets log enumerable properties *anywhere* on the prototype chain on the object:

```js
const theProto = { protoProp: 'val' };
const theInstance = Object.create(theProto);
theInstance.instanceProp = 'val';

console.log(theInstance);
```

The same code in Node only logs the properties *directly on the object*:

> `{ instanceProp: 'val' }`

And `repl.it` runs the code through Node.

Similarly, with your snippet, since the `growl` property is on the *prototype* object, when you log `bBear`, you'll see `growl` in a Stack Snippet, but not if you run the same code in Node.

The actual object in Javascript is the same regardless of your environment - you're not doing anything wrong.

Logging behavior is not standardized. It's engine-dependant.